# How to compare two forecasted graph for two different time series in R?

Tags: r, forecasting

Actually I want to compare the forecasted graph for two different time series data. I have data for 5 year for two different city of rain data which has been observed monthly. For that I have plotted the graph for 5 years of period of time series and also for 2 more year in future using forecast package for both city. Now I want to compare graph these two graphs and their future prediction for 2 years(may be in terms of error).

Can anyone help me out of these.

Comment: Right now your question is much too broad, but take a look at `?cor`, and root mean squared error as a start. Maybe this is more ontopic for Cross-validated stackexchange (not programming but statistics oriented).

Comment: @Paul Hiemstra... Thanks for response. Can you please tell me which one is better for finding the error among correlation, variance and covariance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with something like this:

```
f1 <- forecast(series1, h=24)
f2 <- forecast(series2, h=24)
accuracy(f1)
accuracy(f2)
```

That will give you a lot of error measures on the historical data. Unless you have the actual data for the future periods, you can't do much more than that.

Comment: Are these errors based on the residuals to the model, or is some form of crossvalidation involved?